# In App Purchase does not complete

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I've got one app rejected and the relevant part of the feedback from Apple was:

"In App Purchase does not complete. After selecting the item to purchase, a confirmation window does not appear after waiting over five minutes."

However, in-app purchases indeed work in sandbox mode. I just tested it. Works correctly. What could be the issue? My code pretty much follows Ray's tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial).

Thanks.

--UPDATE 1--

I archived the app and installed it on the device through iTunes and the in-app purchases indeed do not complete as the Apple reviewer stated. I can restore purchases successfully though. If I run it from Xcode the in-app purchases work fine.

--UPDATE 2--

For unknown reasons the in-app purchases are now working in the AdHoc install. I just added some NSLogs around the in-app purchase stuff, and noted that the delegate call to -[IAPHelper productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:] was returning an empty products array. It still does so once and then it is called again containing the expected array.

Comment: I noticed that in distro builds, objects will get deallocated much faster than in development builds, so it's possible that whatever delegate or callback you are using for receiving the purchase confirmation is getting deallocated before it receives the callback from the IAP code. Is your view being popped before the purchase completes? Is the instance variable for the IAP callbacks a declared locally vs. globally in your class?

Comment: From my logs, the delegate call to -[IAPHelper productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:] was returning an empty array of products. For some unknown reason it is working again now. However, this delegate method is called first with an empty array of products, and then it's called again with the correct array. Weird.